spring boot many to many relation ship data not going to associate table error
can someone please explain me why the database (italic and bold part) not working as it should. Also when I sent the data through postman my data is not going to the join (associate) table
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ' __ _ () __  __ _ \ \ \ 
( ( )__ | '_ | '| | ' / ` | \ \ \ 
\/  __)| |)| | | | | || (| |  ) ) ) )
'  || .__|| ||| |_, | / / / /
=========||==============|/=////
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.4.0)
2024-12-28T22:24:26.804+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] c.k.s.StudentCourseApplication           : Starting StudentCourseApplication using Java 17.0.12 with PID 16104 (C:\krishantha\WORK-2024-12\2024-12-19\spring-project\student-course\target\classes started by Krish in C:\krishantha\WORK-2024-12\2024-12-19\spring-project\student-course)
2024-12-28T22:24:26.808+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] c.k.s.StudentCourseApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-12-28T22:24:27.652+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-12-28T22:24:27.729+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 66 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-12-28T22:24:28.511+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-12-28T22:24:28.528+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-12-28T22:24:28.528+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.33]
2024-12-28T22:24:28.607+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-12-28T22:24:28.608+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1738 ms
2024-12-28T22:24:28.818+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-12-28T22:24:28.911+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.6.2.Final
2024-12-28T22:24:28.962+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-12-28T22:24:29.276+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-12-28T22:24:29.316+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-12-28T22:24:29.699+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7cd1ec54
2024-12-28T22:24:29.700+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-12-28T22:24:29.755+05:30  WARN 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQL8Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-12-28T22:24:29.756+05:30  WARN 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: MySQL8Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
2024-12-28T22:24:29.782+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: Database info:
Database JDBC URL [Connecting through datasource 'HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)']
Database driver: undefined/unknown
Database version: 8.0
Autocommit mode: undefined/unknown
Isolation level: undefined/unknown
Minimum pool size: undefined/unknown
Maximum pool size: undefined/unknown
2024-12-28T22:24:30.826+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
Hibernate: create table course_tbl (id integer not null auto_increment, fee float(53) not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table student_course_tbl (student_id integer not null, course_id integer not null, primary key (student_id, course_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table student_tbl (id integer not null auto_increment, address varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table student_course_tbl add constraint FKj1sf76sj2l27g2p06vwutfgjl foreign key (course_id) references course_tbl (id)
Hibernate: alter table student_course_tbl add constraint FK52xq6mvtpownntx0x38jjh7mh foreign key (student_id) references student_tbl (id)
2024-12-28T22:24:31.046+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-12-28T22:24:31.394+05:30  WARN 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-12-28T22:24:31.820+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/'
2024-12-28T22:24:31.828+05:30  INFO 16104 --- [student-course] [           main] c.k.s.StudentCourseApplication           : Started StudentCourseApplication in 5.515 seconds (process running for 5.943)

Please add the application.yaml or properties file from your project

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
